# how to append timezone to Datepipe's tranform function?

Tags: angular, typescript, date-pipe

I want to convert UTC time to specific timezone using angular `DatePipe`.

Without appending timezone, `transform` method converts UTC to local time which i don't want. here's the code.

```
punch_time = this.datepipe.transform('2021-02-05T06:03:40.574000Z', 'shortTime');
```

above code gives output of `11:33 AM`. which is local time.
instead i want to get time in specific timezone for example `UAE - Dubai` time.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular `datePipe` accepts a [`timezone`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#parameters) parameter. But instead of trying to send the ISO8601 timezone abbreviations, I've found sending the [time offset](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.2.2/packages/common/src/i18n/format_date.ts#L363) required work without any issues.

Try the following

```js
punch_time = this.datepipe.transform('2021-02-05T06:03:40.574000Z', 'shortTime', '+4000');
```